# How to convert NSURL to JSON using Swift

Tags: json, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, nsurl

I'm trying to take the response from the graph url (which is in JSON) and save it in a variable, but the thing is that I don't know the syntax to do that and I couldn't find it online, what I have is this line and it's working in getting me the information I need when I type it in a browser:

```
let usercontexturl: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/\(facebookContext)/mutual_friends?access_token=\(access_token)")!
```

And what I want to do is to save the content of the url in a variable, how can I do that?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @JHZ's answer I figured it out, the code I used to do so was this:

```
let myrequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: usercontexturl)
let mysession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = mysession.dataTaskWithRequest(myrequest) { data, response, error in
    do {
        let jsonresult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
        print(jsonresult)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: I really suggest you get some books introducing you to iOS programming. First you need to learn how to download data, given a URL.

Comment: @gnasher729 that's exactly my question, how do I get the data using the url?? I really don't have the time to read a book right now that's why I asked here

Comment: @gnasher729 I know I can use NSData(contentsOfURL:"") but I don't know if that's the right thing to start with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `NSURLRequest`, `NSURLSession`, and `NSJSONSerialization`.

You'll want [this initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLRequest/initWithURL:).

You should feed that into [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:) `NSURLSession` method.

From the completion handler, you can call [this method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData:options:error:) to obtain JSON.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JHZ I could make it work, the code I used to do so was this:

```
let myrequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: usercontexturl)
let mysession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = mysession.dataTaskWithRequest(myrequest) { data, response, error in
    do {
        let jsonresult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
        print(jsonresult)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: It Helped. Thanks Mate. :D